# How to use upsert

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have collection with documents like this

```
[
    { _id : ObjectId("xxxxxx") , u_id : 5 , name : "E" , comment : [1,2] },
    { _id : ObjectId("yyyyyy") , u_id : 4 , name : "D" , comment : [] },
    { _id : ObjectId("zzzzzz") , u_id : 3 , name : "C" , comment : [1,2] },
    { _id : ObjectId("aaaaaa") , u_id : 2 , name : "B" , comment : [1,2] },
    { _id : ObjectId("bbbbbb") , u_id : 1 , name : "A" , comment : [1] },
]
```

Now I have an array of documents prepare to Insert or Update to this collection like this

```
var multi_document =
[
    { u_id : 8 , name : "H" , comment : [1,2] }, //Insert new document
    { u_id : 7 , name : "G" , comment : [] }, //Insert new document
    { u_id : 6 , name : "F" , comment : [1,2] }, //Insert new document
    { u_id : 5 , name : "E" , comment : [1,2,3] }, //update [1,2] to [1,2,3]
    { u_id : 4 , name : "DD" , comment : [1] }, //update D to DD and [] to [1]
    { u_id : 3 , name : "C" , comment : [1,2] }, //not do anything it same original
];
```

Can I use `db.collection.update(multi_document)`; ? If not , What should I do?

This is the expected result:

```
[
    { _id : ObjectId("db_created") , u_id : 8 , name : "H" , comment : [1,2] },
    { _id : ObjectId("db_created") , u_id : 7 , name : "G" , comment : [] },
    { _id : ObjectId("db_created") , u_id : 6 , name : "F" , comment : [1,2] },
    { _id : ObjectId("xxxxxx") , u_id : 5 , name : "E" , comment : [1,2,3] },
    { _id : ObjectId("yyyyyy") , u_id : 4 , name : "DD" , comment : [1] },
    { _id : ObjectId("zzzzzz") , u_id : 3 , name : "C" , comment : [1,2] },
    { _id : ObjectId("aaaaaa") , u_id : 2 , name : "B" , comment : [1,2] },
    { _id : ObjectId("bbbbbb") , u_id : 1 , name : "A" , comment : [1] },
]
```

Comment: `{ u_id : 4 , name : "DD" , comment : [] }, //update D to DD and [] to [1]` which criteria set here?  it should be `{ u_id : 4 , name : "DD" , comment : [] }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is using the ["Bulk"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) API.

First you need to loop over your `multi_document` array and for each document find in your *collection*, documents with same `u_id`. To that we need to use the [**`bulk.find.upsert`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/#Bulk.find.upsert) method which sets the `upsert` to `true` and then use the [**`.update`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/#Bulk.find.update) method which specifies the fields to update, here `comment`. In the update document you need to use the [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet) operator to ensure that there are not duplicate in your comment field and the [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#up._S_each) modifier because `comment` is an array.

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count  = 0;

multi_document.forEach( function (doc) { 
    bulk.find({ "u_id": doc.u_id })
        .upsert()
        .update({
            "$set": { "name": doc.name }, 
            "$addToSet": { "comment": { "$each": doc.comment }}
        }); 

    count++;

    if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {

        // Execute per 1000 operations and re-init. 

        bulk.execute();     
        bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(); 
    } 
})


// Clean up queues

if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

Comment: It working. but the result don't update D to DD. (It created new document and error because i use u_id for unique) 
BulkWriteError({
 "writeErrors" : [
  {       "index" : 4,
   "code" : 11000,
   "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: db.collection.$u_id dup key: { : 4.0 }",
   "op" : {
    "q" : {
     "u_id" : 4,
     "name" : "DD"
    },
    "u" : {
     "$addToSet" : {
      "comment" : {
       "$each" : [ ]
      }
     }
    },
    "multi" : true,
    "upsert" : true
   }}],
 "nInserted" : 0,
 "nUpserted" : 3,
 "nMatched" : 2,
 "nModified" : 1,
})

Comment: Thank you for helping. I will check it too. @user3100115

Answer (score 1):

You could use Bulk() http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/

> With an ordered operations list, MongoDB executes the write operations in the list serially. If an error occurs during the processing of one of the write operations, MongoDB will return without processing any remaining write operations in the list.

Interesting Blog Article about the Bulk API: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/84922794768/mongodbs-new-bulk-api